# Leaflet js geojson coordinates = Lat/lng from googlemap

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am new to leaflet js

Reading the geojson section of leaflet js web site.

A quick question, coordinates in the geojson format, is it same as the lay/lng, which we can get from google map ?

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

yes but you have to invert lat and lng.

For example if you click on Paris you will get following coordinates with GoogleMap: 48.857031, 2.346526

If you generate some geojson with http://geojson.io/ you will get:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.349529266357422,
          48.856414043180365
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also note that GoogleMap only handles 6 decimals (which is ample)